# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $name ]]

Tags: php, oop, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-4

**Warning:** This question is Laravel 4 specific.

I've been using Facades in my controllers before. Therefore I know the code is working. Now I need to introduce dependency injection for various reasons.

After refactoring the controller I get following error:

> Illuminate \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
>
> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $name ]].

I can't figure out where the problem is. The Error message seems cryptic to me and I don't understand it. (I don't see any problem with my `__constructor` parameters since I've registered the binding for the `HelpersInterface`)

Here are the important parts of my code:

**File: app/start/global.php**

```
<?php
 
// ...
 
App::bind('Acme\Interfaces\HelpersInterface', 'Acme\Services\Helpers');
```

**File: composer.json**

```
// ...
 
"autoload": {
    // ...
    "psr-0": {
        "Acme": "app/"
    }
},
 
// ...
```

**File: app/Acme/Controllers/BaseController.php**

```
<?php namespace Acme\Controllers;
 
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application as App;
use Illuminate\View\Factory as View;
use Acme\Interfaces\HelpersInterface as Helpers;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
 
class BaseController extends Controller {
 
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    private $app;
 
    /**
     * @var \Carbon\Carbon
     */
    private $carbon;
 
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\View\Factory
     */
    private $view;
 
    /**
     * @var \Acme\Interfaces\HelpersInterface
     */
    private $helpers;
 
    function __construct(App $app, Carbon $carbon, View $view, Helpers $helpers)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->carbon = $carbon;
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->helpers = $helpers;
 
        $lang = $this->app->getLocale();
        $now = $this->carbon->now();
 
        $this->view->share('lang', $lang);
        $this->view->share('now', $now);
    }
 
    /**
     * Missing Method
     *
     * Abort the app and return a 404 response
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return Response
     */
    public function missingMethod($parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->helpers->force404();
    }
 
}
```

**File: app/Acme/Services/Helpers.php**

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services;

use Illuminate\Config\Repository as Config;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector as Redirect;
use Illuminate\Session\Store as Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Translation\Translator as Lang;
use Illuminate\View\Factory as View;
use Acme\Interfaces\MockablyInterface;
use Monolog\Logger as Log;

class Helpers implements HelpersInterface {

// ...

    public function __construct(
        Config $config,
        Lang $lang,
        View $view,
        MockablyInterface $mockably,
        Log $log,
        Request $request,
        Session $session,
        DB $db,
        Redirect $redirect,
        Response $response
    ) {
        // ...
    }

// ...

}
```

**File: app/Acme/Providers/HelpersServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace Acme\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Acme\Services\Helpers;

class HelpersServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

private $db;
private $defaultDbConnection;

protected function init()
{
    $this->db = $this->app['db'];
    $this->defaultDbConnection = $this->db->getDefaultConnection();
}

public function register()
{
    $this->init();

    $this->app->bind('helpers', function ()
    {
        return new Helpers(
            $this->app['config'],
            $this->app['translator'],
            $this->app['view'],
            $this->app['mockably'],
            $this->app->make('log')->getMonolog(),
            $this->app['request'],
            $this->app['session.store'],
            $this->db->connection($this->defaultDbConnection),
            $this->app['redirect'],
            $this->app['Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response']
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems your `Acme\Services\Helpers` constructor takes a `$name` parameter, but is not type hinted.

Laravel's IoC is not magic. If your don't provide a type hint for every parameter, the IoC container has no way of knowing what to pass in.

Comment: Thanks for your help Joseph Silber.

I've added some more code snippets to show that I've type hinted everything. Also I've got a `ServiceProvider` that should tell the IoC container how to make the concrete `HelpersInterface` implementation. Am i missing something?

Comment: I accepted your answer because you're correct. Laravel did not know how to instantiate the helpers service. This got me on the right track fixing it. I've provided more code snippets and a working solution. You or others may be interested :-)

Comment: @Martin - Just use the full class name (`Acme\Services\Helpers`) as the key in your service provider. That way you can stick to using `App::bind('Acme\Interfaces\HelpersInterface', 'Acme\Services\Helpers')` to register the concrete type (which, BTW, you should do in your service provider via `$this->app->bind()`).

Comment: I have a really simple class that just takes a secret key (string) as an argument. I basically just return a "new MyClass(config('secret')" in the singleton callback. I tried adding a "string" type hint and I still get this error.

Answer (score 49):

For me it was just a matter of running

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: I assume this has something to do with modifying your component file? At least in my case this was the reason. I always have to execute this command when I edit something in my routing file (`web.php`).

Comment: THANK YOU. I'd been chasing these errors for an hour.  I would make code changes and see a different error, which normally exculpates the cache.

Comment: This also helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you use Illuminate\Http\Request; on top of the file instead of any other http import like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

THANK ME LATER!

Comment: in my case i changed
"use HTTP;"
to
"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;"
and the problem resolved

Answer (score 3):

Got it fixed. All the tutorials about dependency injection were referring to concrete implementations of interfaces so that I thought that's the way to go about it. `Joseph Silber's` answer got me on the right track.

The trick is to bind the Interface to the binding of the `ServiceProvider` like shown below. That way Laravel will know how to instantiate the Helpers service.

**File: app/start/global.php**

```
<?php

// ...

App::bind('Acme\Interfaces\HelpersInterface', 'helpers');
```