# Laravel 5 Validator error: Unresolvable dependency resolving

Tags: php, ajax, validation, laravel

I'm having a issue with validation (atleast i believe it's the validation), after submitting a form with ajax to my controller i get the following error:

**BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 872:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [  array $data ]] in class Illuminate\Validation\Validator**

in combination with this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

My Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class ContactController extends Controller {

public function contactProduct(ProductFormRequest $request, Validator $validator)
{
    if (!strlen($request->input('custom'))) {

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            \Mail::send('emails.order',
                $data = [
                    'firstname' => $request->get('firstname'),
                    'lastname'  => $request->get('lastname'),
                    'email'     => $request->get('email'),
                ], function ($message) use ($request) {
                    $message->from($request->get('email'));
                    $message->to('info@example.nl', 'example')
                            ->subject('example');
            });

            return $status = json_encode('success');
        }

        return $errors = json_encode($validator->errors()->all());
    }
}
}
```

My Request file:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ProductFormRequest extends Request {

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname'  => 'required',
        'email'     => 'required|email'
    ];
}

}
```

I've been trying for a long time now, but can't figure out what is wrong. So any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please check link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124360/unresolvable-dependency-resolving-parameter-0-required-name

Comment: Hi, i've seen that post before, but couldn't get me on the right track. I don't understand how it can be applied in my case

Comment: Do you need to do validation twice? The Request should handle the validation.

Comment: Well, the reason i added the if $validator->passes() is because i need to return the validations errors to my ajax when it doesn't passes

Comment: Fixed my issue, didn't have to add validator again