# Unresolvable dependency resolving in class Monolog\Logger

Tags: laravel-5.4

I tried to type in the cli 'php artisan' and it showed me like this:
[cli printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtRlT.png)

Procedures that I also did:
 - composer dump-autoload, composer self-update and then composer update
 - removed vendor directory and then composer install

It didn't answer my question as per flagged as duplicate because it all happened in vendor Monolog/Logger. And I didn't change anything in that setup.

Comment: Your IoC container need a typehint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolvable dependency resolving \[Parameter #0 \[ <required> $name \]\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124360/unresolvable-dependency-resolving-parameter-0-required-name)

Comment: @manniL: not a duplicate because I did not change anything under vendor after I run 'composer update'

Comment: Well, that's weird. Have you checked your permissions and the integrity the composer.json file?