# Laravel Notification Unresolvable Dependency

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, laravel-5, notifications

I'm trying to install the [Laravel Twitter Channel Notification package](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/twitter) into my app that is using Laravel 5.3 and PHP 7.1. I've created the simplest test (go to /tweet route and send a notification to the first user) to verify it *should* be working. Instead I'm getting the following error:

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ 
>   $consumerKey ]] in class Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth

I've read in [other related SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124360/unresolvable-dependency-resolving-parameter-0-required-name) this is because Laravel's IoC doesn't know what to pass in because the constructor (of the package I'm guessing) is not type hinted. Since this is a package I'm not sure the best way to resolve this. Can I overwrite the constructor in my notification class? Below is my test NotificationClass.

```
<?php

namespace app\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

use NotificationChannels\Twitter\TwitterChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Twitter\TwitterMessage;

class TweetNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [TwitterChannel::class];
    }

    public function toTwitter($notifiable) {
        return new TwitterStatusUpdate('Laravel notifications are awesome!');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include the code that you wrote to test this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the dependency interface in your AppServiceProvider's register method. Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

Comment: This shouldn't be needed because there aren't any interfaces being implemented here.

Comment: Do you know the type of $consumerKey? You can bind concrete implementations or static instance, as well, not just interfaces.

Comment: From the package $consumerKey is just a string from the .env file.

Comment: Hmm so looking at the service provider in that package, it should be resolving the Auth dependency. Have you published the packages config file to your config/ directory and added non-empty values?