# value is not assign in the public field of class

Tags: php, laravel, class, laravel-5

I have a class `DashboardController` as

```
class DashBoardController extends Controller
{
    public $str;

    public function __construct($str)
    {
        $this->str = $str;
        echo $this->str;
    }

    public function dashboard(Request $request)
    {
        $obj = new DashBoardController("hello");
        die;
    }
}
```

it gives me Exception as

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $str ]] in class App\Modules\User\Controllers\DashBoardController

What is the error here?

Comment: have you tried by changing name of public $str to something else ?

Comment: I think that you have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124360/unresolvable-dependency-resolving-parameter-0-required-name

Comment: Why do you want to create object of the same class, when you can access all property of the same class easily

Comment: @Vikash Actually there is a need for passing object of this class to other controller for my further code, but i got stuck in this simple code. I don't have any idea why it is behaving like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass default value if there is no dependency injected at the time of load.

```
class DashBoardController extends Controller
{
    public $str;

    public function __construct($str='')
    {
        $this->str = $str;
        echo $this->str;
    }

    public function dashboard(Request $request)
    {
        $obj = new DashBoardController("hello");
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i think you are doing this in wrong way. If you pass any parameter in constructor then you should also assign class for it to inject the dependency directly to the class object. Here `__construct` of `DashBoardController` is immediately called whenever you are hitting related URL because of autoloading feature of framework.

Comment: thanks, i forgot about the autoloading feature of framework, same code is running on fiddle perfectly, so i got confused