# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> array $args ]] in class Aws\AwsClient

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, amazon-dynamodb

When I tried to insert post data in dynamodb-local, following issue happened.
I'd like to know what’s the cause.

**Version**
Laravel: 9.48.0

**Issue**
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  array $args ]] in class Aws\AwsClient

It looks the cause is in constructor since the issue happened when I wrote `DynamoDbClient $client` as an argument in it.

**My code**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler;
use Aws\Sdk;

class ReplyKeywordsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Marshaler
     */
    private $marshaler;

    /**
     * @var DynamoDbClient
     */
    private $client;


    /**
     * DynamoModel constructor
     * @param DynamoDbClient $client
     * @param Marshaler $marshaler
     */
    public function __construct(DynamoDbClient $client, Marshaler $marshaler)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->marshaler = $marshaler;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $replyKeyword = $request->all();
        $replyKeyword = $this->marshaler->marshalItem($request->all());
        $dynamoParameters = [
            "TableName" => "keywords",
            "Key" => $replyKeyword
        ];
        $this->client->putItem($dynamoParameters);
        return redirect("reply_keyword");
    }

}
```

- Cleared cache based on below, but didn’t work.
  [Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $name ]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124360/unresolvable-dependency-resolving-parameter-0-required-name)

I kindly ask for your cooperation.
Thank you.

Comment: The error is that the `DynamoDbClient` needs data for its constructor, but you are not passing them (you can't), so that parameter is unresolvable. Go to the class and you will see it has some parameters, you are not defining what Laravel should pass when resolving the class

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved the issue with searvice provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mr./M(r)s matiaslauriti, I solved the issue.

**App/Providers/DynamoServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Providers;

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\Sdk;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DynamoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Dynamo AWS-SDK接続
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(DynamoDbClient::class, function () {
            $awsSdk = new Sdk([
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => env('AWS_DYNAMO_KEY'),
                    'secret' => env('AWS_DYNAMO_SECRET'),
                ],
                'endpoint' => env('AWS_DYNAMO_ENDPOINT'),
                'region' => env('AWS_DYNAMO_REGION'),
                'version' => env('AWS_DYNAMO_VERSION')
            ]);
            return $awsSdk->createDynamoDb();
        });
    }
}
```

**config/app.php**

```
"providers" => {
  App\Providers\DynamoServiceProvider::class,
}
```

Then I can use DynamoDbClient as argument in constructor.
Thank you.

Comment: Exactly like that, you solved it the Laravel way, kudos to you!